# What is the correct way to modify variables in a Codeigniter helper?

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, captcha, helper

I am using the Codeigniter captcha helper for the first time and I'd like to modify the colors that the helper has defined in RGB in a variable, for example there is:

```
$bg_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);
$border_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 153, 102, 102);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 204, 153, 153);
$grid_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 182, 182);
$shadow_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 240, 240);
```

I've seen people saying to create a helper file in your custom helpers directory but I don't see how that would help here since I don't want to extend the helper, I want to sort override these variables.

So what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you want to extend it is so you can "override" the "create_captcha" function without altering the original helper in your CI system folder. Your CI system should stay untouched so that it's easier for you to update CI on future versions. Also, if something goes wrong in your extended code, you can easily revert back to the original.

1. So create a blank file **application/helpers/MY_captcha_helper.php**
2. Copy only the create_captcha function from system/helpers/captcha_helper.php and paste into MY_captcha_helper.php.
3. Make the changes to those RGB values you want in MY_captcha_helper.php.

Comment: Aha, I see, thanks for clarifying. I'm still relatively new to CI, so thanks for the advice.

Comment: Sure no prob. It's funny because I was just about to set up a captcha in Codeigniter as well. Seems like the best way to keep any bots from potentially submitting some of the more critical forms.

Comment: I had been using reCAPTCHA on all my web forms until now as it is really nice but my problem was that it's just too messy code wise and overcomplicated to style. Issues with w3c standards validation too but then strict was always a bit too strict in my opinion. Codeigniter provides absolute basic (but well made) captcha functionality and we can style it however the heck we want. CI saves my life on a daily basis. Seems every day I find a new function it has that I wish I'd known about before!

Comment: On a final note...have you started playing with Laravel 4? http://four.laravel.com I love Codeigniter and was very very resistant to moving on from it. But it hasn't been worked on in a long time. It seems everyone from CI is moving to Laravel 4 now. I've warmed up to it a bit, and I can tell you that moving to Laravel 4 is one of the best decisions in PHP I've ever made. It comes out of beta this month. So you are just in time :-)

Comment: Awesome, I've actually heard that name thrown around the internet over the last few months but since I just settled into CI I hadn't given it much thought. But now that you and a few others have mentioned it is fantastic, I'll take a look ;)